# Cannot create a cpp project with a static lib in eclipse helios

Tags: c++, eclipse, static, helios

I am trying to create a static library in eclipse. I select New >> C++ Project>> Static Library >> Empty Project >> Cross GCC.

Eclipse then creates a new .a, but in Properties >> C/C++ Build >> Settings instead of having an archiver and assembler there is a G++ compiler and linker in the settings.

I am using the yagarto compiler with eclipse helios CDT 32bit on Windows7. I'm a new user stackoverflow user so I'm not able to post any photos, sorry. Any advice or help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue with an installation of Juno. I could not figure out what was wrong so I reinstalled and then I was able to create static libraries.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I installed Juno and downloaded the updates that I needed and now I have the option to select 'Static Library'.